# Get friends using my app returns empty answer on android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using a new app im creating, right now still not in production, I try to get my friends who also use the app. 
I have one friends listed for now as administrator, and one as a tester, 
I would expect to see them both in the returned data in v2 of facebook graph, yet result remains empty, does anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission will show up in the `/me/friends` endpoint. If they still don´t, you should file a bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/